# Javascript check function arguments

Tags: javascript, oop, function

How do I check that a function has received no arguments?  For example, I want to be able to create a custom function which accepts multiple inputs like so:

```
clear();      // clear all
clear('a');   // clear a
clear('b');   // clear b
clear('c');   // clear c
clear('d');   // clear d
```

Answer (score 7):

You may either check if an argument is [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined):

```
function clear(variable) {
    if (variable === undefined) { ... }
}
```

or simply check the number of [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

```
function clear(variable) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Is one more effective or efficient than the other?

Comment: there's a minor bit of nuanced difference between the two. `clear(undefined)` will clear all in the first, but not in the second.

Comment: @JaPerk14 Agree with *zzzzBov* here. The first will work unless you *need* to pass `undefined` as an argument. Otherwise both variants are same good. Maybe the second is slightly more foolproof.